Is it okay to say ハナちゃんは家を消えた。?
Could the verb 消える used as movement intransitive verbs like 出る、泳ぐ、飛ぶ ? I understand why から sound way more nature, but when I make a sentence like 学校から出る and 学校を出る I think both is grammatically correct but its use is depend. Now back to 消える、if it can't be used like that then why is it?
Also, how do you think about these two sentences
サテライトは地球を打ち上がった。
お化けが家を現れた。

What do you intend the sentence to mean? The 'go out' meaning of 消える is very different from the 'go out' meaning of 出る.

There is no movement associated with the intransitive verb 消える【きえる】.  A better gloss in various contexts might be "vanish".  In English, you cannot sensibly say, "Hana vanished home", just like in Japanese, you cannot sensibly say, 「ハナちゃんは家【いえ】を消えた【きえた】」. Similarly, there is no movement associated with the intransitive verb 現れる【あらわれる】, so using this transitively likewise results in nonsense. And while 打ちあがる【うちあがる】 does include a sense of movement, the nuance of あがる seems close enough to passive that using this with を conveys a different nuance than you appear to intend.

Isn't disappearing a kind of movement that head to the void?

How do you understand the function of を? As you say, for example,  disappeared into the dark can be translated to 闇に消えた. But not を. Roughly it is a accusative marker and disappearing does not involve affecting something so that 消える never comes with を. Similar for the others.

Affecting something... I think I kinda get it now but, can I use that to explain for cases like 家を出る?

As for how far you can extend the use of this type of を, this question might help.

The short answer is "No". The core meaning of 消える is to become invisible, and the verb doesn't necessarily involve "movement". Likewise, you cannot say ～を現れる, either.
When 消える clearly indicates leaving a place in context, something like この街を消えていく or この世界を消えて別の世界に旅立つ is actually not incomprehensible, and I found several similar examples in real lyrics. However, such usage is nonstandard and rare, and I recommend that learners avoid using ～を消える. It's likely to be marked wrong on exams.
While 打ち上がる certainly always involves some form of movement, we don't use を with it, either, probably because it's not an active action.

Isn't the core meaning of 消える more like "vanish" or "disappear," rather than "become invisible"? (In English, when something is "invisible" it is still present, although it cannot be seen, while my dictionary defines 消える as 目に見えていたものが なくなって ，見えなくなる (emphasis added).
